# Two nonevident implications in a proof

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am reading part of Lee's introduction to mainfolds. I got to the following proposition.

> $\textbf{Proposition 14.7.}$ *Suppose $H\subset N$ is an integral manifold of an involutive distribution $D$ on $N$. If $F:M\to N$ is a smooth map such that $F(M)\subset H$, then $F$ is smooth as a map from $M$ to $H$.*
>
> *Proof.* Let $p\in M$ be arbitrary, and set $q=F(p)\in H$. Let $(y^1,...,y^n)$ be flat coordinates for $D$ on a neighborhood $U$ of $q$. Choose coordinates $(x^i)$ for $M$ on a connected neighborhood $B$ of $p$. Writing the coordinate representation of $F$ as $$(y^1,...,y^n)=(F^1(x),...,F^n(x)),$$ the fact that $F(B)\subset H$ means that the coordinate functions $F^{k+1},...,F^n$ take on only countably many values. Because $B$ is connected, the intermediate value theorem implies that these coordinate functions are constant, and thus $F(B)$ lies in a single slice. On this slice, $(y^1,...,y^k)$ are coordinates for $H$, so $F:N\to H$ has the local coordinate representation $$(y^1,...,y^k)=(F^1(x),...,F^k(x)),$$ which is smooth. $\tag*{$\square$}$

I am having trouble between the two displayed lines of the proof. Precisely, my questions are:

1. How does $F(B)\subset H$ imply $F{k+1},\dotsc,F^n$ take only countably many values?
2. How does the connectedness of $B$ (which of course implies that of $F(B)$ since $F$ is smooth and thus continuous) imply, by the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), that those functions are constant?

Comment: The excerpt that you quoted is not from either of the published editions of my book  -- it's from an illegally pirated early draft of the first edition, which I never gave anyone permission to post. I would not recommend that you try to learn about smooth manifolds from it, because it's full of errors.

Comment: It is pretty curious that a _Jack_ Lee says I'm reading a pirated copy of his book when the book says it' by a _John M._ Lee. Did the pirates get the name wrong? Besides, I'm finding it great for the moment. I've read through the part about differential forms, skipped Riemannian metrics, read about distributions and integral manifolds, and am now reading about foliations. My thesis is about periodic orbits in Hamiltonian fields on convex surfaces, and I've never done anything about forms on manifolds, and all I know about distributions and foliations is straight out of this book.

Comment: Btw I just found an errata for that copy.

Comment: @MickG You might want to view this, and be more respectful... http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/

Comment: I apologize for my comment. If I read that right, the name is John M, and Jack is a nickname or the likes. Is that right @JackLee? In any case, I liked that book, and I'm pretty sure the correct version is even better. At the moment I have finished reading what I planned to read, but if I change my plans, I will consider getting the correct version.

Comment: Or should I say Professor @JackLee :)?

Comment: Yes, Jack is a nickname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) This follows from the previous theorem - $N \cap U$ consists of countably many 'vertical slices' (that is, $N \cap U$ takes only countably many values of the coordinate functions $F^{k+1}, \dots, F^n$.)
2) Given any countable subset of the reals, its connected components are just points. (You should try to prove this!) This generalizes to $\Bbb R^n$ for all $n$.

(Side note: it looks like you're using the first edition of Lee's book. I think the second one is generally a bit better organized.)

Comment: I can easily show that the path connected components of a subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ which is countable are the points. That is because to have a continuous path in $\mathbb{R}$ you need to not skip any number between the endpoints, that is to take every value in the interval between the endpoints, and this is not possible in $A$ since it has Lebesgue measure 0 and thus cannot contain an interval. But the connected components? I can easily get to the fact every point is closed in $A$, but I would try showing every point is clopen, yet that is not true as for example $\{0\}$ is not clopen…

Comment: …in $\mathbb{Q}$, because $\mathbb{Q}\smallsetminus\{0\}$ is not closed since 0 is a limit point of it via e.g. the sequence $\frac1n$. So how do I proceed? I would have to show each two-point subset of $A$ is disconnected, that would be easy, but not enough, because if I take greater subsets I would fill up space between points and that might lead to connection.

Comment: Perhaps the only connected subsets of the reals are intervals? I seem to remember a similar result from Analysis 1 two years ago…

Comment: If a subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is not an interval, then I can find $a\leq c\leq b$ such that $a,b\in A$ but $c\not\in A$. Then I can take $(-\infty,c)\cap A,(c,+\infty)\cap A$ and those are two clopen sets of $A$. OK, got it.

Comment: As for the general case, I think I can show it is contained in a cartesian product $\times A_n$ of countable subsets of the reals. If $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is countable, I can take $B=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\exists0\leq i\leq n,z\in A:z_i=x_i\}$. That is a cartesian product, precisely it is the cartesian products of the sets $A_i=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\exists z\in A:z_i=x\}$, and it clearly contains $A$. So if I can prove this kind of products have points as connected components, I am done.

Comment: OK the above reduction is useless. Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be countable. Let $p_i(x)=x_i$ be the projection on the $i$th coordinate. In other words, $p_i(x)=x\cdot e_i$, $e_i$ being the $i$th canonical vector, and $\cdot$ being the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Those maps are continuous, so if $S\subseteq A$ is connected, so is $p_i(S)$, for all $i$. But $p_i(S)$ can be at most countable, so the connected components if that set are the points. So for each $i$, the connected components of $A$ have a fixed value for the $i$th coordinate, meaning they are points.

Comment: Could you edit this into your answer for the sake of completeness?